# What causes Offset too large exception when using CURL?

Tags: node.js, curl, exception, https

I am using the CURL command:

`curl https://127.0.0.1/api/v1/devices/csrattrs -s -v --cacert ./cacert.pem --capath ./ | openssl base64 -d -A | openssl asn1parse -inform DER`

to get the csrattrs of a certificate mimicking RFC7030. I'm sending through a self signed CA certificate. When I run the command with -v I get the output (condensed for clarity):

```
* subjectAltName: host "127.0.0.1" matched cert's IP address!
* SSL certificate verify ok.
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< X-RateLimit-Limit: 100
< X-RateLimit-Remaining: 89
< Date: Fri, 02 Sep 2022 14:46:27 GMT
< X-RateLimit-Reset: 1662130457
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 26
< ETag: W/"1a-GQNbY0Y54h9X9g6znIBxjch9Hpw"
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
< 
{ [26 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
Error: offset too large
```

I'm new to CURL and haven't found an answer to what the offset is referring to.

Comment: This error comes from OpenSSL, not cURL. From what I can see you are working with a PEM, which should be PEM-encoded, so why are you using `-inform DER`?

Comment: I'm new to both CURL and openssl. My understanding is the pem file is used for authentication and that the response gets piped from the base 64 encoding to inform DER. Should the pem file be .crt? The -inform DER was part of the request from the website testRFC7030 so I just copied it.